# How to place GDI+ Bitmap onto the clipboard?

Tags: winapi, gdi+, clipboard

I want to place a GDI+ [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534420(v=vs.85).aspx) onto the clipboard. The obvious way would be to:

- use [`Bitmap.GetHBITMAP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms536295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create an `HBITMAP`
- use [`SetClipboardData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to place the `HBITMAP` onto the clipboard as a `CF_BITMAP`

So i try *pseudo-code*:

```
void PlaceBitmapOnClipboard(Bitmap image)
{
   //Convert GDI+ Bitmap to GDI Bitmap
   HBITMAP bmp;
   image.GetHBITMAP(0, @bmp);

   OpenClipboard(this.Handle);
      EmptyClipboard();
      SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, bmp);
   CloseClipboard();
}
```

Error checking has been omitted for expository purposes; but neither function fails:

- Not `GetHBITMAP` and its `HRESULT` style error
- Nor does `SetClipboardData` return a `null`

But when i try to *use* the `CF_BITMAP` on the clipboard, it can't be pasted into Paint:

[image]

So, what is the correct code to fill in the function:

```
void PlaceBitmapOnClipboard(Bitmap image)
{
   //TODO: Ask Stackoverflow to figure this out

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to call:
`SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbitmap_ddb)`

Where `hbitmap_ddb` must be a compatible bitmap (DDB), not DIB which we get from `Gdiplus::GetHBitmap`

---

Or we call:
`SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, hmemory)`

Where `hmemory` is not `HBITMAP`. `hmemory` is described in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) as:

> A memory object containing a `BITMAPINFO` structure followed by the
>   bitmap bits.

---

**Example using `CF_BITMAP`**

Use `CreateDIBitmap` to create a compatible bitmap based on our DIB bitmap. Then call `SetClipboardData` with the new DDB bitmap.

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap gdibmp(L"file.bmp");
if(gdibmp.GetLastStatus() != Gdiplus::Ok)
    return;
HBITMAP hbitmap;
auto status = gdibmp.GetHBITMAP(0, &hbitmap);
if(status != Gdiplus::Ok)
    return;
BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof bm, &bm);
DIBSECTION ds;
if(sizeof ds == GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof ds, &ds))
{
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    HBITMAP hbitmap_ddb = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, &ds.dsBmih, CBM_INIT,
        ds.dsBm.bmBits, (BITMAPINFO*)&ds.dsBmih, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    if(OpenClipboard(hwnd))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbitmap_ddb);
        CloseClipboard();
    }
    DeleteObject(hbitmap_ddb);
}
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
```

---

**Example using `CF_DIB`**

Use `GlobalAlloc` to allocate memory, and copy `BITMAPINFOHEADER` to that memory, followed by the bits. There is no need to worry about the color table, because `Gdiplus::HBitmap` returns 32-bit bitmap (at least on modern displays as far as I know)

```
Gdiplus::Bitmap gdibmp(L"file.bmp");
if(gdibmp.GetLastStatus() != Gdiplus::Ok)
    return;

HBITMAP hbitmap;
auto status = gdibmp.GetHBITMAP(NULL, &hbitmap);
if(status != Gdiplus::Ok)
    return;
BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof bm, &bm);

BITMAPINFOHEADER bi =
{ sizeof bi, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, 1, bm.bmBitsPixel, BI_RGB };

std::vector<BYTE> vec(bm.bmWidthBytes * bm.bmHeight);
auto hdc = GetDC(NULL);
GetDIBits(hdc, hbitmap, 0, bi.biHeight, vec.data(), (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, 0);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);

auto hmem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, sizeof bi + vec.size());
auto buffer = (BYTE*)GlobalLock(hmem);
memcpy(buffer, &bi, sizeof bi);
memcpy(buffer + sizeof bi, vec.data(), vec.size());
GlobalUnlock(hmem);

if(OpenClipboard(hwnd))
{
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, hmem);
    CloseClipboard();
}
DeleteObject(hbitmap);
```

---

Comment: Instead of making a device-dependent copy of the DIB section, you can probably just put the DIB into the clipboard, if you use the right format.  Try `SetClipboardData(CF_DIB, hbmp)`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy most paint programs don't check the clipboard for DIB

Comment: The clipboard will convert between CF_DIB and CF_BITMAP as necessary to satisfy requests.  And Microsoft recommends putting DIBs on the clipboard over device-dependent bitmaps in order to avoid undesired color changes due to custom palettes:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Synthesized_Clipboard_Formats

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I just tried it again with Microsoft paint, wordpad, word, and windows mail, none of them work with `CF_DIB`, they work with `CF_BITMAP`, unless I am doing something wrong...

Comment: This works! I tried the original bitmap handle with both `CF_DIB` and `CF_DIBV5`. Both fail on the call to `SetClipboardData` with error code 6 (*The handle is invalid*). Looks like you cannot no way no how put a DIB (or whatever GDI+ returns you) on the clipboard.

Comment: Indeed, you can't put the GDI+ handle directly in, but you can get the DIB from the GDI+ handle, and put that DIB on the clipboard as a CF_DIB, which is the recommended way according the MSDN link I posted earlier.

Comment: According to the [`GetObject` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) you can only pass `sizeof(DIBSECTION)` if the handle was returned by `CreateDIBSection`, which is not the case here. So if this answer really works, it relies on undocumented implementation details.

Comment: @GetFree `GetObject(..., sizeof DIBSECTION, ...)` expects a DIB. Documentation doesn't say if this DIB has to be created directly with `CreateDIBSection`. I added error check to test for `GetObject` success in case. Also `DIBSECTION` is optional, there are other methods to retrieve the data for calling `CreateDIBitmap`

Comment: The documentation cannot be more explicit about this: ***HBITMAP returned from a call to CreateDIBSection***

Comment: For the record, I'm not saying that your code doesn't work, or that it shouldn't work or that it could fail in some cases. All I'm saying is that it contradicts the documentation, that's all.

Comment: @GetFree Note that `GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof ds, &ds)` would be useless if the only place to use it is immediately after `CreateDIBSection`. You already know the info which you supplied to `CreateDIBSection`, what is the point of getting that info through another API? I think the documentation is weird.

Comment: Also I checked Microsoft's ATL `CImage` class, it too uses `GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof ds, &ds)` where `hbitmap` is loaded with Gdiplus or `LoadImage(..., LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)`.

Comment: I forgot to free `hbitmap`, please see edit. Also I added another method for using `CF_DIB`